# RACSignal: Why use rac_textSignal a "defer" to return a RACSignal to self?

Tags: ios, reactive-cocoa

The [rac_textSignal-Implementation](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa/blob/swift-development/ReactiveCocoa/Objective-C/UITextField%2BRACSignalSupport.m#L20) uses "defer" to return a RACSignal on "self".
What is the reason for that?

This is the implementation:

```
- (RACSignal *)rac_textSignal {
    @weakify(self);
    return [[[[[RACSignal
        defer:^{
            @strongify(self);
            return [RACSignal return:self];
        }]
        concat:[self rac_signalForControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged]]
        map:^(UITextField *x) {
            return x.text;
        }]
        takeUntil:self.rac_willDeallocSignal]
        setNameWithFormat:@"%@ -rac_textSignal", [self rac_description]];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Both the deferred signal and the concatenated signal send `UITextField`s (effectively `self`).

The deferred signal makes the returned signal send the currently stored text on subscription, as `[self rac_signalForControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged]` only sends on changes.

Comment: Why is the defer necessary?

Comment: Likely to fit in the weakify/strongify dance. Edit: Looks like Jakub reached the same conclusion.

Answer (score 1):

If you were to omit defer and implement it like:

```
- (RACSignal *)rac_textSignal {
    @weakify(self);
    return [[[[[RACSignal return:self]
            concat:[self rac_signalForControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged]]
            map:^(UITextField *x) {
                return x.text;
            }]
            takeUntil:self.rac_willDeallocSignal]
            setNameWithFormat:@"%@ -rac_textSignal", [self rac_description]];
 }
```

I still don't understand `RAC` memory management perfectly, however, in above implementation your signal will have strong reference to `self`, won't ever complete and you will end up with zombie `UITextField`.

Answer (score 0):

I think defer is just to prevent retain cycle